# How to return only the first occurrence of an ID with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a large collection called `Messages`, like so:

```
{
   user: 94fg844f,
   event: null,
   group: null,
   name: "Jake",
   text: "Hello world"
}, {
   user: fje93jrg4,
   event: null,
   group: null,
   name: "Bob"
   text: "Testing"
}, {
   user: fje93jrg4,
   event: null,
   group: null,
   name: "Bob"
   text: "Text here"
}, {
   user: null,
   event: d0j3n9fn3,
   group: null,
   name: "My Event"
   text: "Testing 2"
}, {
   user: null,
   event: d0j3n9fn3,
   group: null,
   name: "My Event"
   text: "Another text"
}
```

I need to get the first occurrence of the users, events and groups.

For example, since user `fje93jrg4` occurs twice, I just want to get the document back with the text of `Testing` since the one with the text of `Text here` is older than it. Same goes with the `event` of `d0j3n9fn3`. It occurs twice, although I just want to get the first document back of it with the text of `Testing 2`.

I looked into `distinct` although it seems to only support one search term, like `user` instead of `user`, `event` and `group`.

The final result of the above would be:

```
{
   user: 94fg844f,
   event: null,
   group: null,
   name: "Jake",
   text: "Hello world"
}, {
   user: fje93jrg4,
   event: null,
   group: null,
   name: "Bob"
   text: "Testing"
}, , {
   user: null,
   event: d0j3n9fn3,
   group: null,
   name: "My Event"
   text: "Testing 2"
}
```

My guess is that I'll probably have to use an `aggregate` with `$first` or something along those lines. The problem with doing 3 different queries is that I need to apply a limit so that I always get 10 results back. For example, there could be no recent `group`s in the mix, just `event`s and `user`s.

Comment: Could you just append the three searches together? Also, those 3 searches seem very different. An array for the output almost seems inappropriate because the index is meaningless.

Comment: @4castle - Only probably with that is that a limit cannot be applied.

Comment: How do identify the first and last document for each user. You can't rely on documents' order in the collection.

Comment: @user3100115 - should have stated that, my bad. I can either use the '_id' as a sort, or a custom 'created' field that each document has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the aggregation framework to do this. First we need to [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) by `user` and "_id". From there, we then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by "user" and use the [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) accumulator operator to return the last document for each user. Note that we can also use the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) accumulator operator if we sort our documents in descending order, but sorting in ascending order and using `$last` make our intention clear.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "user": 1, "_id": -1 } }, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$user", 
        "user": { "$last": "$$ROOT" } 
    }} 
])
```

which produces:

```
{
    "_id" : "fje93jrg4",
    "user" : {
        "_id" : 2,
        "user" : "fje93jrg4",
        "event" : null,
        "group" : null,
        "name" : "Bob",
        "text" : "Testing"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : "94fg844f",
    "user" : {
        "_id" : 1,
        "user" : "94fg844f",
        "event" : null,
        "group" : null,
        "name" : "Jake",
        "text" : "Hello world"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : null,
    "user" : {
        "_id" : 4,
        "user" : null,
        "event" : "d0j3n9fn3",
        "group" : null,
        "name" : "My Event",
        "text" : "Testing 2"
    }
}
```

We may want to add a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project) to our pipeline but doing so will cause a drop of performance. However it will reduce both the amount of data sent over the wire and the time and memory used to decode documents on the client side if do not need all of the key/value pairs in a document returned.

The `$project`  stage look like this:

```
{ "$project": {
    "_id": "$user._id",
    "user": "$user.user",
    "event": "$user.event",
    "group": "$user.group",
    "name": "$user.name",
    "text": "$user.text"
}}
```

Comment: Looks good! Although what would happen on the rare occurrence that a `user` and `event` have the same ID? They are different collections, and my `Messages` collection just references their IDs.

Comment: You don't need to consider the "event" field here. All you need is the "user" and the "_id" or the "created" field as you mentioned in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582331/how-to-return-only-the-first-occurrence-of-an-id-with-mongoose/37662481?noredirect=1#comment62794852_37582331)

Answer (score -2):

Works Perfect:

db.getCollection('Mytest').aggregate([{ $match : { user: "fje93jrg4" }},{$limit:1}])

Comment: I don't think you read the question at all. I'm not searching for a specific user, I need to return the first result of each user, group and event...