# Return records in mongoDB based on top 1 of field x grouped by type y

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

If i have the following json structure:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        type: "Drinks",
        isActive : "true",
        location: "QLD"   
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        type: "Drinks",
        isActive : "false",
        location: "NSW"  
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        type: "Drinks",
        isActive : "true"
        location: "QLD"   
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        type: "Drinks",
        isActive : "false"
        location: "QLD"   
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        type: "Drinks",
        isActive : "true"
        location: "QLD"   
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        type: "Food",
        isActive : "true"
        location: "NSW"   
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        type: "Food",
        isActive : "false"
        location: "NSW"   
    }
]
```

The return i'm interested in is:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        type: "Drinks",
        isActive : "true",
        location: "QLD"   
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        type: "Drinks",
        isActive : "false",
        location: "NSW"  
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        type: "Drinks",
        isActive : "true",
        location: "QLD"    
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        type: "Food",
        isActive : "false",
        location: "NSW"    
    }
]
```

In other words, `give me top 1 of each TYPE in each LOCATION sorted by ID descending`. The records may be repeated as the sample data set looks so essentially i want all the unique types for each location.  Is this something that can be done in mongoD?

It many not be relevant but i am using Mongoose within my nodejs app to interact with mongoDB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return only the first occurrence of an ID with Mongoose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582331/how-to-return-only-the-first-occurrence-of-an-id-with-mongoose)

Comment: Or this [Group Mongo documents by id and get the latest document by timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603622/group-mongo-documents-by-id-and-get-the-latest-document-by-timestamp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aggregation framework is at your disposal to give you the desired results. You would have to run an aggregation pipeline consists of 3 stages, in the following order:

1. **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)**

   - This pipe will allow you to first order the documents getting into the pipeline for grouping later. Sort the documents with the `ID` descending.
2. **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)**

   - The group pipeline operator is similar to the SQL's `GROUP BY` clause. In SQL, you can't use `GROUP BY` unless you use any of the aggregation functions. The same way, you have to use an aggregation function in MongoDB as well. 
     In this instance, you need to group all the documents by the `type`, `location` and `id` keys, and use the required **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** operator to bring in the first document (in other words, the `TOP` document when ordered).
3. **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)**

   - This pipeline step is similar to `SELECT` in SQL. Use this to rename the field names and select/deselect the fields to be returned, out of the grouped fields. If you specify 0 for a field, it will NOT be sent in the pipeline to the next operator.

---

Putting all the three pipes together, you can run the following aggregation pipeline to achieve the required result:

```
var pipeline = [
    { "$sort": { "id": -1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "type": "$type", "location": "$location", "id": "$id"
            },            
            "isActive": { "$first": "$isActive" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "id": "$_id.id",          
            "isActive": 1,
            "type": "$_id.type",
            "location": "$_id.location"
        }
    }
]

Model.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, result) {
    if err throw err;
    console.log(result);
});
```

Or using the fluent API

```
Model.aggregate()
    .sort("-id")
    .group({
        "_id": {
            "type": "$type", "location": "$location", "id": "$id"
        },            
        "isActive": { "$first": "$isActive" }
    })
    .project({
        "_id": 0,
        "id": "$_id.id",          
        "isActive": 1,
        "type": "$_id.type",
        "location": "$_id.location"
    })
    .exec(unction(err, result) {
        if err throw err;
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Comment: is it required to specify all fields in the pipeline? There may be more than isActive in the model so i rather return all fields and not care what fields it contains apart from the ones i am querying on.

Comment: The response structure in in question says what i'm looking for. I want all the fields returned but the matching criteria should be `give me top 1 result of each type sorted by id", so simply i don't want duplicated types in response result.

Comment: I think you can stop your pipeline right after the `$group` stage if you use `$last: "$$ROOT"` to return the last document for each group, which I think is more efficient.

Comment: @chridam i updated the question with the expected response. specifically the expected query should give `top 1 of each TYPE in each LOCATION sorted by ID descending`

Comment: @JohnYounan Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:-

```
db.collname.aggregate(
[
 {
   $group:
     {
       _id: "$type",
       id: { $max: "$id" }
     }
 }
]
```

Refer [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#use-in-group-stage) for more info.